# C appending number to filename if file already exists

Tags: c, file, server, client, strtok

Im trying to write a function that will append a number to a filename if that file already exists before I create the new file. This is for a file transfer between a client and server.

For example if the client sends a file name "Example.txt" but the server already has a file named "Example.txt" I would like to change the file name to "Example-1.txt" and if that already exists increase the number to "Example-2.txt" and keep going until the filename doesn't exist.

It should also work in the case the filename is "Ex.x.x.x.x.txt" or "Ex.--1.txt" and change them to "Ex.x.x.x.x-1.txt" and "Ex.--2.txt" respectively.

I have tried using the strtok() method but the code has gotten long and messy. I have tried searching online and I haven't found anything regarding this problem. I feel like I am trying to reinvent the wheel when there has to be a better way to solve this problem.

EDIT- This is what I came up with. One problem that I can see with it is at a certain point when the number to append is too big, there will be a segfault because Im hardcoding the extra memory to allocate to file path.

```
void check_if_file_exists(char **filepath, const char *filename, const char *directory)
{
    struct stat file_status;

    if (stat(*filepath, &file_status) == 0)
    {
        char *final_filepath, *new_filepath, *filename_extension;
        size_t filepath_size;
        int append;

        filepath_size = strlen(filename) + strlen(directory) + 64;
        append = 1;

        final_filepath = safe_malloc(filepath_size);
        new_filepath = safe_malloc(filepath_size);

        strcpy(new_filepath, directory);

        filename_extension = strrchr(filename, '.');

        strncat(new_filepath, filename, filename_extension - filename);
        strcat(new_filepath, "-%d");
        if (filename_extension != NULL)
        {
            strcat(new_filepath, filename_extension);
        }

        do
        {
            sprintf(final_filepath, new_filepath, append++);

        } while (stat(final_filepath, &file_status) == 0);

        *filepath = final_filepath;

        free(new_filepath);
    }
}

void *safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr = malloc(size);

    if (!ptr && size > 0)
    {
        perror("Malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the doco for `strrchr()`? There's two 'r's in the middle of that function name.

Comment: Start at the end of the filename and find the last `.`. Save the name without that part somewhere and start a counter at 1. Construct the new name using the base you saved and the counter and check the server. Repeat the last step until the server says it's okay increasing the count on every failure..

Comment: "I have tried using the strtok()" --> Post that try.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I added my solution as an answer but I've added it to my question now.

Comment: Valiant effort... but... What if the filename is `"ABC...DEF.txt"`? `strtok()` will regard those contiguous `'.'` as a single instance. The filename will be changed to `"ABC.DEF.txt"` ... Is this important to your application?

Comment: @Fe2O3 I have changed my code and it should work for all the cases I can think of. And thank you for mentioning strrchr() but when I had originally searched the function I was looking at the documentation for strchr().

Comment: New code might not handle filenames without extensions. (Eg: "report"). Consider `do/while()` to avoid duplicating `sprintf()`... Calling function needs to know whether or not to `free()` allocated buffer... `memset()`'s unnecessary... Could replace `filename_size + directory_size` with appropriate `strlen()`'s directly and not have two variables. Otherwise, looks okay...

Comment: I have updated the code to account for filenames without extensions like "report". but it won't work for "rep.ort". Do you mean the calling function needs to ```free()``` filepath? @Fe2O3

Comment: Especially important to long-running processes (like a server) is that there are no memory leaks... Eroding available heap memory will work... until it doesn't. Also important is verifying the return value from `malloc()`. I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: The code allows an extra 4 bytes (eg: injecting "-27", with a trailing nul). Good. But there's no protection when `append` counts higher than 99... Buffer overrun...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255408/discussion-between-programmer-and-fe2o3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readers... FYI: Before DV'ing, please examine the timestamps and edit revisions of the OP's question and this answer. The code now present in the question appeared hours after this answer was posted. (Or, go ahead and DV, if you must.)

So, here's a prototype of what might work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

int nextName( char *cp ) {
    char *sufx = strrchr( cp, '.' );
    char *sp, hold[16] = {0}; // enough for ".txt" or ".html"

    if( sufx )
        strcpy( hold, sp = sufx );
    else
        sp = cp + strlen( cp );

    int i = 0;

    do {
        struct stat sbuf;
        if( stat( cp, &sbuf ) != 0 && errno == ENOENT )
            return 1;

printf( "%s exists... Moving on\n", cp ); // debugging

        sprintf( sp, "-%02d%s ", i, hold );
    } while( ++i < 100 );

    return 0;
}

int main( void ) {
    char str[ 32 ] = "Example.txt";

    puts( str );
    if( !nextName( str ) ) {
        /* Handle case where no higher version number is possible */
    }
    puts( str );

    return 0;
}
```

Create two files, "Example.txt" and "Example-00.txt", in the current directory. This will detect their existence and modify the filename until it finds "Example-01.txt" is not currently there. And so on...

This *should* even work if the filename has no extension.
Example: "foobar" and "foobar-01"...

Caution: The buffer containing the desired path must be LARGER so that the extra 3 characters can be 'tacked in/on' to the filename.

There is an inherent *race condition* if multiple processes may be writing to the same directory.

(You could trivially change this to use 000->999 versions of each file. Adapt to suit your needs.)

---

**EDIT:**
Having considered that a path could be "this.dir/filename", the above needs to be improved by the following:

```
/* Scan right to left examining only the filename part of a path. */
char *fndExt( char *cp ) {
    char *p = cp + strlen(cp) - 1;
    for( ; p >= cp && *p != '/' && *p != '\\'; p-- )
        if( *p == '.' )
            return p;
    return NULL;
}

int nextName( char *cp ) {
    char *sp = fndExt( cp, '.' );
    char hold[16] = {0}; // enough for ".txt" or ".html"

    if( sp )
        strcpy( hold, sp );
    else
        sp = cp + strlen( cp );

    int i = 0;

    do {
        /* same as above */
```

There may be a need for a larger `hold[]` buffer to account for pathologically long filenames that have a `'.'` more than 30 characters from the end of the name. Or, `findExt()` could be modified to only look for `'.'` 4-5 characters from the end of the filename and presume that to be the file's extension. Much depends on context. Is the file named "Mr.Bar" a name with an extension?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to the problem:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define FILE_EXIST(name)  (access((name),0) != -1)
#else
    #include  <io.h> 
    #define FILE_EXIST(name)  (_access((name),0) != -1)
#endif

char szOutFileName[100] = "MYFILE.txt";
int tries = 0;

    /* Where FILE_EXIST(char *name) is some method that tells if a filename exists or not.
    ** (Many ways to do).*/
    while(FILE_EXIST(szOutFileName)) /* Loop breaks when we achieve a unique name...*/
        sprintf(szOutFileName, "MYFILE%d.txt", tries++); /* tweak name with increment*/
```